# ORDER BY and LIMIT in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, limit, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to get a subset of records in a GROUP BY, I've seen a lot of crazy solutions out there, but they just seem too complicated, is there any more efficient way to do this.

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY `timestamp`) AS items 
FROM wb_user_book_current_item GROUP BY user_id
```

So this will return me all the current items for all users which is okay so far.  But I only want the ten most recent items.  Adding `ORDER BY` to the `GROUP_CONCAT` helps, but it still doesn't give me the last ten records.

**EDIT**

If I do something like this and hard code the `user_id` then I can get the results I want for that one user, problem is combining it so that I don't need to hard code the `user_id` and can for instance just get **ALL** users last ten items

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cp2.item_id) AS items 
FROM (SELECT cp.user_id, cp.item_id 
      FROM wb_user_book_current_item cp 
      WHERE cp.user_id=1 ORDER BY cp.`timestamp` 
      LIMIT 10) AS cp2 
GROUP BY cp2.user_id
```

Comment: Maybe you have to put LIMIT 0,10 at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So came across a nice solution here that works pretty well.

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

It's something like this put all together:

```
SET @num := 0, @user_id := '';

SELECT cp2.user_id, CONCAT(cp2.item_id) AS items
FROM (
   SELECT cp.user_id, cp.item_id,
   @num := IF(@user_id = cp.user_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
   @user_id := cp.user_id AS dummy
   FROM wb_user_curent_item AS cp
   ORDER BY cp.user_id ASC, cp.`timestamp` DESC
) AS cp2 WHERE cp2.row_number <= 10
GROUP BY cp2.user_id
```

So basically it just uses the `num` increment to limit the records rather than using `LIMIT`

Answer (score 6):

This is a difficult problem, but how about this:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY `timestamp`) AS items
FROM wb_user_book_current_item T
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM wb_user_book_current_item T2
    WHERE T2.user_id = T.user_id
    ORDER BY T2.`timestamp` DESC
    LIMIT 10,1
) 
OR T.`timestamp` > (
    SELECT T2.`timestamp`
    FROM wb_user_book_current_item T2
    WHERE T2.user_id = T.user_id
    ORDER BY T2.`timestamp` DESC
    LIMIT 10,1
)
GROUP BY user_id
```

This of course assumes you won't have two rows with the same `timestamp` for the same user.

If your timestamp field is always a positive integer, you can also replace the `NOT EXISTS...OR` with a `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY `timestamp`) AS items
FROM wb_user_book_current_item T
WHERE T.`timestamp` > COALESCE((
    SELECT T2.`timestamp`
    FROM wb_user_book_current_item T2
    WHERE T2.user_id = T.user_id
    ORDER BY T2.`timestamp` DESC
    LIMIT 10,1
), 0)
GROUP BY user_id
```

---

Original answer, but apparently MySQL doesn't understand how to do this properly and complains the subselect returns multiple rows. Of course we want multiple rows; it's a `GROUP_CONCAT`. Grr.

Unfortunately, I think there's no real way around using a subquery:

```
SELECT T.user_id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT T2.item_id 
                  FROM wb_user_book_current_item T2 
                  WHERE T2.user_id = T.user_id 
                  ORDER BY T2.`timestamp` 
                  LIMIT 10)) AS items 
FROM wb_user_book_current_item T
GROUP BY user_id
```

Otherwise, adding `LIMIT` anywhere else will either limit the number of groups, or limit from the total recordset over the table (and not the group) - neither of which are what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Agreed  I didn't see the group_concat - op will have to use sub query in conjunction with limit

Comment: Having issues with this, so the `SELECT` returns multiple rows as it should, but the `CONCAT` happens after that so I get a "multiple rows" error since it's trying to put it all into one record.  Still working on trying to `CONCAT` it some other ways, but just can't seem find a way yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    i.user_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(i.item_id ORDER BY i.timestamp) AS items 
FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id
      FROM wb_user_book_current_item 
    ) AS du
  JOIN
    wb_user_book_current_item AS i
      ON  i.user_id = du.user_id
      AND i.timestamp <= COALESCE(
          ( SELECT i2.item_id 
            FROM wb_user_book_current_item AS i2
            WHERE i2.user_id = du.user_id
            ORDER BY i2.timestamp ASC 
              LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9
          )
          , '2038-01-19 03:14:07')
GROUP BY
    i.user_id ;
```

An index on `(user_id, timestamp, item_id)` will help efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(item_id ORDER BY `timestamp`) AS items 
FROM wb_user_book_current_item 
GROUP BY user_id
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: This will limit the number of final results, not the results of items for each users.

Answer (score -2):

UPDATE: I didn't notice the GROUP_CONCAT so you will have to use sub query in conunction with LIMIT

use LIMIT

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
LIMIT number
```